# Custom loop for getting products flagged as new

Tags: woocommerce

I was looking for a way to build a custom loop to get the products flagged with the "new" label.

I could use the sort from the insert time, but that would always include a certain number of products, my goal here is to get those products that conform to the WooCommerce setting that says the product is considered new for a given number of days.

Answer (score 0):

i have a free plugin - [WooCommerce Product Badge](http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-badge), it has your requested feature to display "New" label with certain days defined.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Terry, but actually what I need is a bit different. WooCommerce already has a flag to mark products as new for a given X number of days. All I need is to have a custom loop using that property as query filter.